# ¿Como abrir y mostrar imagenes de directorio con php?

Tags: php, html, imagen, .htaccess

Hola  a todos tratando de proteger mis imagenes he creado un archivo .htaccess en mi directorio de imagenes, este es mi codigo:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Pero he notado que aun puedo acceder a mis imagenes con la libreria fpdf que cuenta con una funcion llamada image: `$this->Image('uploads/logoempresa/1.png',10,6,30);`

Y dado que no puedo acceder directamente con la etiqueta html a mis imagenes me gustaria imprimirlas usando alguna funcion de php. Ya que no quiero que puedan acceder a mis imagenes terceros y que solo se puedan abrir desde php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal vez esto te pueda servir:

```
<?php
$img = "comment.png";
$dat = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
$src = 'data:'.mime_content_type($img).';base64,'.$dat;

echo "<img src=\"$src\">";
?>
```

Comment: Es lo que buscaba desde hace tiempo!